# Asymmetric strictly balanced graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-graphs, existence-theorems

I am interested in the existence of strictly balanced, asymmetric graph with given number of vertices and edges.

A known result of [Rucinski and Vince](https://people.clas.ufl.edu/avince/files/StronglyBalanced.pdf) shows that for every $(v,e)$ with $1\leq v-1 \leq e \leq\binom{v}{2}$ there exists a strictly balanced graph with $v$ vertices and $e$ edges. However, their construction may yield symmetric graphs. Is it possible to find an asymmetric construction, say if $e$ is linear in $v$? Is something like that known? I could not find relevant results.